# Dar todos los permisos a un usuario mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo una aplicacion en php5 y mysql y estoy intentando ejecutar un query pero me sale un error que dice:

> Error al crear la base de datos: Access denied for user
>   'root1'@'localhost' to database 'nada'

Así que entre a phpmyadmin e intente darle permisos con el siguiente query

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root1'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Pero no tuve exito me sale igual que no tengo permisos para dar permisos o algo asi adjunto imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El usuario desde el cual ejecutas la consulta debe tener privilegios para otorgar privilegios a otros usuarios, de lo contrario no funcionará. Tampoco me parece una buena idea dar privilegios totales sobre todas las bases de datos a `root1`, ¿es realmente eso lo que quieres o es asignar esos privilegios sobre una BD en específico?

Comment: Si eso quiero, como puedo hacer para que mi usuario pueda dar todos los privilegios?

Comment: Tendría que dárselos un usuario (por ejemplo el administrador) u otro que tuviera esa potestad. Estudia bien lo de los permisos y su alcance antes de empezar a distribuir llaves (permisos) a cualquiera sin saber qué puertas va a abrir y con qué conciencia sobre la gravedad o no de abrirlas.